# Declared variable but can't reach it from HTML <script>-tag

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I tried to reach my declared variable from another file than it was declared, but I failed. Maybe it was the -tag causing this, I atleast thought so at the begging. My 'merit' variable is defined like this:

```
function GetSelectedItem()
{
    var merit;
}
```

Why can't I reach it from outside my file?

Comment: Show your code for a better understanding

Comment: Don't you understand it? I'm trying to reach a variable located in a JS-file outside of my HTML-file. The JS-file is declared in the HTML-file but nothing more. What do I need to do?

Comment: You need to post your code here!

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand, yes. We can't see your code, we're not sure what you're trying to do. Edit the question with the basics of what you need/want.

Comment: Updated with code, and basically what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @TommieMichaelLagerroos You need to be much more precise in your question. What did you try to access that didn't work? What was on the JS console? What's the difference between expected and actual behavior? What's the smallest amount of code that can reproduce the same, or at least similar, output? Etc. That's 600+ lines of code and we don't know what you actually *need*. I made some assumptions, but you shouldn't *force* us to make assumptions. [This question is being discussed on meta as part of a larger question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182400/the-downvote-and-run-issue).

Comment: I'm sorry not really making myself understood and I never meant to sound mean or something, of course it's my fault not really asking the question right and being kinda silly. I'll take this critics to the next question and I'll try only to focus on the error, and not publishing 600+ lines of code. Sorry for all anger I made with this question.

Comment: Guys, I updated the question. It's a bit easier to understand know. I'm doing this for future use. Sorry about the bad expressions of the old question. Really fell this one is easier to understand, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that great mess of JavaScript is what you actually have, and you're trying to access the variable `merit` from your HTML file, you can't: `merit` is scoped inside a function, and unavailable outside of that function.

You *could* make it a global like a large portion of your other variables, this would solve the immediate problem, assuming your JS is processed before anybody clicks.

That is a giant hunk of very-similar JS; I might reconsider your code's organization.

Comment: Yeah that's true, didn't think about that. Haven't really finished my training of javascript but this I should really know. Anyway, thank you for the wake-up call!